# How to provide icons and notification control for snap apps?

Tags: notifications, thirdpartyapps

I downloaded Spotify app via snaps and it doesn't show up in app list. Notifications also fall under "other" category.

I searched that to add an application icon, I should add `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` Apps from snap have those files under `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`. Should I simply copy that file?

Will adding `X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true` allow me to control the notifications from Spotify separately from other apps?

Comment: Snaps often don't appear until you've rebooted or at least logged out and logged back in. Have you done that yet? (I am not sure about the rest, but the snap apps may not appear until you've rebooted.)

Comment: Oh! That fixed the issue of Spotify showing app in app list. Then I'll add the `X-GNOME-UserNotifications=true` in original `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` and that should do it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With help of @KGIII I've found the answer.
I needed to login and logout to see the apps in AppCenter. Adding `X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true` in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications` allows controlling notifications for snaps separately. The only persisting issue is that they still appear combined in the notification centre.